# what file need to edit for cancelling the non paid order

Tags: orders

We are using a magento extension for custom payment methods[citrus].

In that extension, for pending orders, we are not able to cancel the order.

I want to know what folder and file i need to edit to fix this issue....

I mean under "Block", "Config", Or "model" ? This is indexcontroler.php

```
<?php 

require 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';

class CitrusPay_Moto_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('moto/form_pay')->toHtml());
    }

    private static function _generateHmacKey($data, $apiKey=null){
        $hmackey = Zend_Crypt_Hmac::compute($apiKey, "sha1", $data);
        return $hmackey;
    }

    public function paymentAction()
    {
        $txnid = "";
        $txnrefno = "";
        $TxStatus = "";
        $txnmsg = "";
        $firstName = "";
        $lastName = "";
        $email = "";
        $street1 = "";
        $city = "";
        $state = "";
        $country = "";
        $pincode = "";
        $mobileNo = "";
        $signature = "";
        $reqsignature = "";
        $data = "";
        $flag = "dataValid";
        $respdata = "";

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
        $orderid=-1;

        $apiKey = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/moto/apikey');

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        {
            $signatureFlag = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/moto/matchSignature');

            $postdata = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

            $txnid = $postdata['TxId'];
            $data .= $txnid;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Citrus Transaction Id: </strong>".$txnid;

            $orderid=$txnid;
            $order->loadByIncrementId($orderid);

            $TxStatus = $postdata['TxStatus'];
            $data .= $TxStatus;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Transaction Status: </strong>".$TxStatus;

            $amount = $postdata['amount'];
            $data .= $amount;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Amount: </strong>".$amount;

            $pgtxnno = $postdata['pgTxnNo'];
            $data .= $pgtxnno;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>PG Transaction Number: </strong>".$pgtxnno;

            $issuerrefno = $postdata['issuerRefNo'];
            $data .= $issuerrefno;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Issuer Reference Number: </strong>".$issuerrefno;

            $authidcode = $postdata['authIdCode'];
            $data .= $authidcode;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Auth ID Code: </strong>".$authidcode;

            $firstName = $postdata['firstName'];
            $data .= $firstName;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>First Name: </strong>".$firstName;

            $lastName = $postdata['lastName'];
            $data .= $lastName;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Last Name: </strong>".$lastName;

            $pgrespcode = $postdata['pgRespCode'];
            $data .= $pgrespcode;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>PG Response Code: </strong>".$pgrespcode;

            $pincode = $postdata['addressZip'];
            $data .= $pincode;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>PinCode: </strong>".$pincode;

            $signature = $postdata['signature'];

            $respSignature = self::_generateHmacKey($data,$apiKey);

            /* Suppose a Custom parameter by name Roll Number Comes in Post Parameter.
             * then we need to retreive the RollNumber as
            * $rollNumber = $postdata['Roll Number'];
            * For other custom parameters as well this code can be used to retreive them. */

            if($signature != "" && strcmp($signature, $respSignature) != 0)
            {
                $flag = "dataTampered";
            }
            $txMsg = 'CitrusPay: '.$postdata['TxMsg'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Citrus Transaction Message: </strong>".$txMsg;
            $txnGateway = $_POST['TxGateway'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Transaction Gateway: </strong>".$txnGateway;
            /*$issuerCode = $_POST['issuerCode'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Issuer Code: </strong>".$issuerCode;
            $paymentMode = $_POST['paymentMode'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Payment Mode: </strong>".$paymentMode;
            $maskedCardNumber = $_POST['maskedCardNumber'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Card Number: </strong>".$maskedCardNumber;
            $cardType = $_POST['cardType'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Card Type: </strong>".$cardType;*/
            //Mage::log("Citrus Response received is ".$TxStatus);
            //Mage::log("Citrus Response Message is ".$txMsg);
            //Mage::log("Citrus Response signature recieved is ".$signature);
            //Mage::log("Citrus Response signature generated is ".$respSignature);
            if($TxStatus == 'SUCCESS')
            {
                if($signatureFlag == 'Y')
                {
                    if($flag != "dataValid")
                    {   
                        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);                      
                        $order->addStatusHistoryComment("Citrus Response signature does not match. You might have received tampered data")->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                        $order->cancel()->save();
                        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setErrorMessage("<strong>Error:</strong> Citrus Response signature does not match. You might have received tampered data");
                        Mage::log("Citrus Response signature did not match ");
                        $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure');
                    }else{
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($txMsg);
                        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
                        $order->addStatusHistoryComment($txMsg)->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                        $order->save();                     
                        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();    
                        Mage::log("Citrus Response Order success..");
                        $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success');
                    }

                }
                else {
                    Mage::log("Citrus Response - Must enable signature validation in Admin...");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
                // Inventory updated 
                $this->updateInventory($orderid);
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment($txMsg)->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->cancel()->save();               
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setErrorMessage("<strong>Error:</strong> $txMsg <br/>");
                Mage::log("Citrus Response Order canceled ..");
                $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure');
            }
        }
        Mage::log("Citrus Transaction END from Citruspay");
    }

    public function updateInventory($order_id)
    {

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
        {
           $ordered_quantity = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
           $sku=$item->getSku();
           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
           $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId())->getQty();

           $updated_inventory=$qtyStock + $ordered_quantity;

           $stockData = $product->getStockItem();
           $stockData->setData('qty',$updated_inventory);
           $stockData->save(); 

       } 
    }


}
```

Comment: Which extension you are using ? May be it will be controllers .Check Index controller

Comment: we are using citrus pyment extension, please check updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `paymentAction()` is your *return url  of payment gateway* and **$order** give `proper order object` then using `below code you can cancel order`.

```
$order->cancel()->save();
```

Comment: please tell me where i need to place this code

Comment: i already told,You need to put this code at paymentAction() if `f paymentAction() is your return url of payment gateway `

Comment: please help me how i can find "paymentAction()" is our return url

Comment: Before implement the payment method at magento,every payment  indian gateways  asking  from which url you will send request to  payment gateway &  from which url  payment gateway return

Comment: sorry, but cirus team did't asked about this . i will check with that team and reply you.

Comment: Can you please share,ur  of cirus

Comment: i didt got reply from them, i will update you soon.

Comment: Please share citrus magento module